# Uninitialised string offset: 11 in F:\xampp\htdocs\practice\temp\rev_string.php on line 6

Tags: php

I am trying to display the string in reverse, without using any built-in PHP functions. My code is working, but it's giving me a notice of uninitialized string offset on line no. 6.

```
<?php
    $str = "Tausif Raut";
    $k=0;
    while ($str[$k] != '') {
      $k++;
    }
    $len = $k;

    for($i = ($len-1);$i>=0; $i--){
        echo $str[$i];
    }

?>
```

Comment: `while ($str[$k] != '') {` just doesn't cut it, an out of bounds array is an out of bounds array.

Comment: How can i fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need 2 loops, just use 1:

```
$str = "Tausif Raut";

for($i = strlen($str) -1; $i>=0; $i--){
  echo $str[$i];
}
```

Output:

> tuaR fisuaT

If you really don't want to use build in functions, you can supress messages:

```
<?php
  $str = "Tausif Raut";
  $k=0;
  while (@$str[$k] != '') {
    $k++;
  }

  for($i = ($k-1);$i>=0; $i--){
    echo $str[$i];
  }

?>
```

However, never, ever shall I recommend using `@` as it's is a design flaw.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know i can do it with strlen function. but i don't want use any of php function

Comment: @TausifRaut I saw that in your question, but you will need to know the length of the string. This is viable in lower level languages as well, such as [tag:c++]